# Magento `customer_save_before` event

Tags: magento, events

`customer_save_before` event is called both when a customer is created and when a customer makes changes to their account. How can I distinguish whether an account already exists or user is making some change to account information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try checking for the existence of a customer id on the object in your observer.

```
if($customer->getId() == null) {
  // New Customer
} else {
  // Existing Customer
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have found out this question. We can use also `hasId()` as well. Thanks a lot!